# Array prepends 1 at the back when changing from javascript to php/laravel

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this javascript array

```
[
  "spiderman",
  "xmen",
  "barbie",
  "avengers"
]
```

It is what I see on the screen when I open http://localhost:8080

If I decide to show it in laravel using this code in a controller :

```
    public function showReccPosts(){
        $name='alice';

        // Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8080/?name=$name",
    CURLOPT_PROXY => '',
]);
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$results = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

       return view('reccomended.index',compact('results'));

    }

}
```

And in a blade file:
`{{$results`

I get:

```
[
  "spiderman",
  "xmen",
  "barbie",
  "avengers"
]1
```

What is up with the 1 attached at the end of the array?
Will it stop me from from performing functions on the array?
By the way,can I even use that type of array (from js to php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CURL request isn't returning the content to your PHP code and is probably just displaying it.  You then are taking the return from CURL (the `1`) to say it succeded and then displaying that.  Change the options to capture the return value by setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`...

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8080/?name=$name",
    CURLOPT_PROXY => '',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);
```

Comment: Thanks.It removed the `1` but gave me this:
[
  &quot;spiderman&quot;,
  &quot;xmen&quot;,
  &quot;barbie&quot;,
  &quot;avengers&quot;
]

Is there  any way I can safely transferthe array from nodejs to php and php will still treat it as an arraY?

Comment: You can use something like `html_entity_decode()` on `$results` to convert it.

Comment: If you need to manipulate it in PHP - you can then have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: But php treats it as a string

Comment: But it is not json.It is a js array which is converted to a string by php